# Command, doesn't work without a space, how can I fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

Alright, my code is bugging me a lot, it doesn't seem to work without a leading space, for my discord bot.

I would like it to work either in both ways, or just without the space, how can I do this.

Here is my code:

How can I change my code so that it works both ways, or just without the space.

````
    await ctx.send("Select an amount of time for the giveaway.")
    try:
        since = await client.wait_for('message', check = check, timeout=30.0)

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("You took to long, please try again!")


    seconds = ("s", "sec", "secs", 'second', "seconds")
    minutes= ("m", "min", "mins", "minute", "minutes")
    hours= ("h", "hour", "hours")
    days = ("d", "day", "days")
    rawsince = since.content
    
    
    try:
        time = int(since.content.split(" ")[0])
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.send("You did not specify a unit of time, please try again.")
        
    since = since.content.split(" ")[1]
    if since.lower() in seconds:
        timewait = time
    elif since.lower() in minutes:
        timewait = time*60
    elif since.lower() in hours:
        timewait = time*3600
    elif since.lower() in days:
        timewait = time*86400
    elif since.lower() in weeks:
        timewait = time*604800
    else:
        
        return await ctx.send("You did not specify a unit of time, please try again.")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    temp = re.compile("([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)")
    res = temp.match(since.content).groups()
    time = int(res[0])
    since = res[1]
```

```
This should work!
```

Comment: Not sure if that `try` is part of the code or you suggesting the OP to actually try that code. `try` can't come alone. It needs an `except` or at least a `finally` after it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract the values:

```py
import re

...

time, unit = re.findall('(\d+) *(.+)', since.content)[0]
```

Comment: `try:
        time, unit = re.findall('(\d+) *(.+)', since.content)[0]
        time = int(since.content.split(" ")[0]) `


do i do this?

@Yevhen Kuzmovych